# Quartz.net + Task Parallel Library

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, quartz.net

I'm working on upgrading a job scheduling system we use in-house that uses Quartz.net. Looking at the source of the latest version of Quartz, I noticed that it still uses its own thread pool implementation, as opposed the much-improved thread pool (or anything from System.Threading.Tasks) that started shipping with .NET 4.0.

I'd be curious to know if anyone has successfully implemented a job scheduling system that uses Quartz.net for its scheduling features and TPL for thread pooling. Is it relatively easy to swap out Quartz's thread pool for that of TPL? Is Quartz even still relevant in the world of Tasks? Alternatively, as sold as I am on the great improvements with the .NET 4.x thread pool (core awareness, local queues, improved locking, etc.), is Quartz's thread pool good enough for typical coarse-grained background jobs and not worth the effort of forcing TPL into the mix?

Thanks in advance for any insights on using (or not using) these two tools together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quartz.NET is there to solve a bit different problem than TPL. Quartz.NET is intended for recurring job scheduling with rich set of capabilities for *execution timing*. TPL on the other hand is meant for highly performant parallel execution of computational workload.

So in essence you (usually) use Quartz.NET for precision scheduling and TPL for conccurent workloads that needs to be completed as quick as possible utilizing all computing resources (cores etc).

Having said this, I'd say the thread pool implementation that Quartz.NET uses is quite sufficient for the job. Also bear in mind that Quartz.NET is .NET 3.5 compliant and cannot use 4.0 only features.

Of course, you can also always combine the two in your solution.

Comment: Thanks. I think you confirmed my hunch that maybe you don't need a super turbo-charged thread pool for running slow unattended background jobs.

Comment: Are there any potential pitfalls with using the two in combination? To give an example, I want to schedule a job that, when it's triggered, gets its work from the database, and this work may be 50-100 individual pieces of work, which I want to do in a Parallel.ForEach. Are there conditions where this would blow up?

Comment: They should work together just fine. Just have your normal logging and exception handling routines in place. Think it like if you Program.cs's Main would throw, it's the same thing. You might want to consider setting retry flag to context on error, or just wait for next execution - it's good idea to make the job idempotent.